# Upgrade site to 3-tier configuration

Tags: upgrade, site, tiered

I've been tasked to upgrade an existing sharepoint site to a 3-tier architecture to support the addition of another, client-facing site.  Can someone point me in the right direction for a resource for this?  I've been asked to write out the tasks required to do this and I've never done it before, although I have a lot of experience with Sharepoint customizations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to start by reading up on the difference between a farm (which is the thing you need to make 3-tier) and a site: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/sharepoint-terminology-farm-web-application-site-collection-top-level-site/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a two tier farm with one Web Front End (WFE)/application server and one SQL Server. I also assume you will add a single application server and moving application task (services) from the WFE to the new application server. My third assumption is that you will configure a second WFE and add both WFE's to Network Load Balancer (NLB).

This architecture is quite common, but you don't have to/shouldn't restrict which WFE who is supports which farm. Let's leave that task to the NLB who does this for us. Sometimes Site two will have heavy traffic and supporting it from two WFE's greatly improves performance.

## Steps to take

- Install SharePoint on both of your new servers
- Activate the appropriate services (SharePoint and supporting services) on your application server. Stop the appropriate services on both WFE's. Verify that SharePoint is running correct
- Configure NLB and add both WFE's two the NLB.

More to read: [Install SharePoint 2013 across multiple servers for a three-tier farm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805948.aspx)